# Angular build product is error with isDevMode()

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to build a project with the command `ng build --prod`.
But I get message error when running web:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.`

I have used `isDevMode()` to check some logic code.

- main.ts:

```js
import 'hammerjs';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

- order.service.ts

```js
const url: string = isDevMode() ? 'http://[::1]:3000/orders' : '/orders';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {
...
}
```

Please help me fix it.

Comment: Do you have SSR enabled, because that has two `main.ts` files and it sounds like both are mapped to your TypeScript compile paths.

Comment: Can you explain more detail about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is not produced by the `isDevMode()` call. I cannot reproduce this error with this code. Usually, this error is trown when you try to call `enableProdMode()` after `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`. Are you calling this somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I have many service file and I use `isDevMode()` in each service files